# Understanding alternating current (sine wave)

Tags: signal, waveform

I want to study the basics of propagating a periodic signal, i.e. [sine waveform](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine_wave), which is a power signal.

Let us consider an alternating current and write its expression as

$$I(t) = I_m \sin(2\pi f t)$$

Let f=50Hz

In physics we have learned that there are mainly two types of energies based on position and based on the motion of particle.

1. Potential energy (P.E.)
2. Kinetic energy (K.E.)

Can anybody explain something about the following issues:

1. If we consider the period from \$0\$ to \$2\pi\$, in what proportions the above 2 energy values vary at following intervals \$0\$,\$\frac \pi 4\$,\$\frac \pi 2\$ ,\$\frac {3\pi} 2\$ ,\$2\pi\$ that make the sine wave **keep propagating**?
2. Why the traveling wave is sinusoidal?

Comment: Sine wave is a mathematical function. It has no energy, unless describing some physical system behavior.

Comment: question (2): represent \$sin(\theta)\$ as the vertical component of a vector as it rotates anticlockwise from \$\theta=0\$ and you'll see how the rate of change of \$\theta\$ reduces between \$0\$ and \$90^o\$

Comment: What kind of Wave? Electromagnetic? Therefore, you miss a lot of parameters for these types of waves.

Comment: @MathieuL you can consider alternating current as sine wave and explain relative to it.

Comment: @Eugene you can consider
alternating current as sine wave
and explain relative to it.

Comment: Kinetic energy of current? No, I can't.

Comment: @Chu you can consider
alternating current which is a sine wave
and explain relative to it.

Comment: @Eugene sir,for any signal to propogate,it must possess some energy within it. is it right?

Comment: ...I thought I'd done that. What don't you understand?

Comment: @Eugene also as the signal is moving from one point to other, it has to have some kinetic energy.

Comment: @user Kinetic energy is given by `1/2 * mass * velocity^2`. Can you tell me please the *mass* of a signal?

Comment: @Eugene I don't know whether mass and magnitude of the signal are same teams or not but magnitude of the waveform is **|A|**

Comment: @Eugene let resistance be 1 ohm. then using the formula I.e. $$E=|x(t)^2|$$ ,we calculate energy of the signal **x(t)**. then if we consider above sine wave as signal then 1. can we consider energy of signsl at wt=π/4 as potential energy and 2. energy of signsl at wt=0 as kinetic energy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the sense of classical physics (and hence classical electromagnetism a la Maxwell) EM fields have nothing to do with kinetic energy, which is a mechanical concept related to the mass of a body.

In modern physics you could consider photons and their *equivalent* mass, i.e. their relativistic mass (as explained [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/2233/49126)). But in Maxwell's theory, which is part of classical physics, electromagnetic waves have no mass, so it makes no sense to talk about their kinetic energy. They do have some energy content, but this is explained in terms of "traveling" potential energy, i.e. the electric and magnetic field in a region of space possess some potential energy; if the fields propagates, so does the energy associated with them. This is expressed using the [Poynting vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poynting_vector).

From what you say it seems to me that you are mixing up concepts of different fields, in particular signal theory and electromagnetism.

In signal theory we *define* the energy of a time signal \$y(t)\$ as:

\[
E_y = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \left| y(t) \right|^2 dt
\]

whereas we *define* its power as:

\[
P_y = \lim_{T \to +\infty}{\dfrac 1 T \int_{-T/2}^{+T/2} \left| y(t) \right|^2 dt }
\]

It is a well-known result of signal theory that signals that have finite energy have zero power and signals with finite power have infinite energy. All these definitions have nothing to do with the physical meaning of energy and power! They are mathematical definitions applicable to any signal that can be expressed mathematically.

In fact \$y(t)\$ could have any physical dimension (or can be dimensionless), therefore it's energy (as per above definition) will have \$[y]^2\cdot T\$ dimensions, where \$[y]\$ means "dimension of the quantity y". For example, if y represented a voltage, the dimensions of \$E_y\$ would be \$V^2 \cdot T \$ (units \$V^2\cdot s\$ then), which are *not* the physical dimensions of the "physical energy". Moreover, y could well be, for example, a pressure level, so it would be measured in *pascal* (Pa), hence the dimensions of \$E_y\$ would be \${Pa}^2\cdot s\$, again not an energy in physical sense.

Now, let's examine your example:

\[
y(t) = A \cdot \sin(2\pi f t )
\]

you say you want to study propagating signals, but y does not represent a propagating signal, since there is only one independent variable. Even restricting your study to a mono-dimensional case, i.e. just one spatial coordinate (say \$x\$), you would have a more complicated mathematical expression, like the following:

\[
y(x,t) = A \cdot \sin \left[2\pi \; \left(\dfrac x \lambda - f t  \right)  \right]
\]

where \$\lambda\$ is the wavelength of your signal.

The wavelength is analogous to the period of a periodic signal, but referred to the spatial dimension (like a "spatial period"). In other words it is the length along the x axis after which the signal repeats itself.
Note that mathematically the signal \$y(x,t)\$ above is periodic both along the x (spatial) axis and along the time axis. Try to plot that signal along the x axis for different values of t and you'll see a sinusoidal wave "moving" along the x axis (toward more positive values).

Let's tackle your point 1. Energy has nothing to do with the propagation of an EM wave. Whether or not a wave propagates depend on the sources of the EM wave (e.g. an antenna) and on the medium in which the sources are immersed. The fact that a traveling EM wave carries some energy with it is a consequence, not the cause, of the propagation. In the vacuum a propagating wave will keep on propagating forever even if its energy content will be spread in an ever-growing volume of space (spherical waves). There won't be an energy threshold that blocks the energy from propagating *in general*.

Interaction with physical media is extremely more complex. There could be media in which a wave will be attenuated as it progresses along, making the wave lose energy in the process, thus leading to a gradual fading. There could be media in which an incident wave could not even pass (total reflection, as in a mirror hit by light). And there could be media that could even distort the form of the wave. That's an enormous can of worms, and the only general approach is to solve Maxwell's equation knowing the constitutive relations for the media the EM wave is supposed to interact with.

Let's consider point 2. Why it takes less time to go from 0 to 0.7A than from 0.7A to A? Well, that's simply a mathematical property of the sin function. There is no physical explanation, if this is what's you're looking for. Maybe the question you should ask is: "why a traveling wave is sinusoidal?". Well, the answer is "in general a traveling wave is not required to be sinusoidal". Sinusoidal waves are common just because it's very easy to analyze them and they are among the simplest solutions of Maxwell equations. Moreover they are the basis for more complex methods that allow to decompose a complex waveform into sinusoidal components (Fourier analysis and the like). But you can have traveling waves with arbitrary waveforms. For example, in most PC's high-speed buses signals travel as waves but they are not sinusoidal, but usually rectangular, because on those buses you transmit digital information (0-1, Hi-Low - and I won't bother you with details on digital signals which are not just two levels or "square").

Answer (score 3):

Since you prefer an Alternating current analogy , I will try to explain both of your concerns with the help of a simple parallel LC circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdqhBi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Suppose initially that capacitor was charged to some charge Q. In this configuration, it will begin to discharge through the inductor. Thus it will start to lose energy which is stored in the form of Electric field.

```
U =  ( Q^2 ) / 2C
```

Now flowing charges constitute current. Current will increase in the circuit. As a result the energy stored in the inductor, which is in the form of Magnetic field will start to increase.

```
U = ( L * I^2) / 2
```

Ultimately, the capacitor will lose all of its charge and energy will be completely stored in the form of magnetic field.

But wait, inductor has one special property : It prevents any abrupt change. So what does that mean?

Although energy is completely magnetic now, the flow of current cannot stop, because inductor doesnt allow it to suddenly stop.

So now the capacitor comes into play. It is discharged, so charge begins to pile up on its plates due to current flowing in the circuit. And capacitor begins to charge itself, and the cycle continues.

Now regarding your second query, why is the rate different. If you observe carefully, that should be pretty much expected. Lets take capacitor for example.

Initially (after the capacitor has discharged) , it has no or very little charge. So piling up more charge on its plates doesnt really require much effort. As charge begins to pile up, the electrons already present on the plate begin to oppose the incoming charge. So it basically requires more time to put charges on the plate. So you see the graph initially jumps pretty quickly, but then the rate drops as more charges are put on the plates.